# iptables unknown option INPUT?

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to run the following command to create a rule in my iptables ubuntu 14.04:

```
# sudo iptables -A INPUT -udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
```

Only problem is everytime I run it. the command line responds

```
iptables: unknown option "INPUT"...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant something like this:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
```